# How can I combine two dataframes based on a column of lists in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

### Reproducible setup

I have two dataframes:

```
df=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':['xy','yx','zy','zz'],
                        'B':[[1, 3],[4, 3, 5],[3],[2, 6]]})

df2=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'B':[1,3,4,5,6],
                        'C':['pq','rs','pr','qs','sp']})
```

`df` looks like:

```
    A          B
0  xy     [1, 3]
1  yx  [4, 3, 5]
2  zy        [3]
3  zz     [2, 6]
```

`df2` looks like:

```
   B   C
0  1  pq
1  3  rs
2  4  pr
3  5  qs
4  6  sp
```

---

## Aim

I would like to combine these two to form `res`:

```
res=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':['xy','yx','zy','zz'],
                        'C':['pq','pr','rs','sp']})
```

ie

```
    A   C
0  xy  pq
1  yx  pr
2  zy  rs
3  zz  sp
```

The row with `xy` in `df` has the lsit `[1,3]`. There is a row with value `1` in column `B` in `df2`. The `C` column has value `pq` in that row, so I combine `xy` with `pq`. Same for the next two rows. Last row: there is no value with 2 in column `B` in `df2`, so I go for the value `6` (the last row in `df` has the list `[2,6]`).

---

## Question

How can I achieve this without iterating through the dataframe?

---

A very similar post in [Spanish SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/416289/merge-en-columna-de-valor-con-columna-de-lista), which inspired this post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `explode` "B" into separate rows, then merge on "B" and drop duplicates.

Big thanks to Asish M. in the comments for pointing out a potential bug with the ordering.

```
(df.explode('B')
   .merge(df2, on='B', how='left')
   .dropna(subset=['C'])
   .drop_duplicates('A'))

    A  B   C
0  xy  1  pq
2  yx  4  pr
5  zy  3  rs
7  zz  6  sp
```

---

Ideally, the following should have worked:

```
df.explode('B').merge(df2).drop_duplicates('A')
```

However, pandas (as of writing, version 1.2dev) does not preserve the ordering of the left keys on a merge which is a bug, see [GH18776](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18776).

In the meantime, we can use the workaround of a left merge as shown above.

Comment: either it's a pandas bug - but the inner join doesn't seem to be respecting the order (it seems to be ordering it based on "insertion" order of the left keys) - you can see the value for `yx` should be `pr` but this returns `rs`

Comment: a left join with `dropna` followed by `drop_duplicates` fixes this

Comment: there's already a bug open on this : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18776